# What mechanism causes the presence of photosensitizers in mitochondria to change membrane ionic currents?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, pharmacology, cell-membrane

In the original question, the article in question was talking about specifically about this compound, Benzoporphyrin:

[Characterization of Perturbing Actions by Verteporfin, a Benzoporphyrin Photosensitizer, on Membrane Ionic Currents](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fchem.2019.00566/full)

From my original understanding, the addition of a photosensitizer to the mitochondria of a cell and the presence of appropriate light causes a change in the ionic membrane current. Nonetheless, from knowledge of photodynamic therapy, using the benzoporphyrin would create reactive oxygen species, which would wreak havoc on the mitochondria.
Yet this is not the case and it also changes the membrane potential.

I originally wondered what was the mechanism behind this and I still do, however the article goes on to describe a multitude of varying research papers on the similar topic on various types of photosensitizers as if it were common knowledge, yet I could still not find an underlying explanation for this application's.

I will link the other papers which the original article refers to, but this seems to be a wide topic and not reserved solely to this paper. I hope this makes it easier to answer.

-Papers-: [1](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fchem.2019.00566/full#B60)
[2](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fchem.2019.00566/full#B63)
[3](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fchem.2019.00566/full#B64)

Comment: Would the changes in currents show the direction/specificity expected by unspecific damage to mitochondria? Generally there are more ways to break something rather than to improve functionality (https://www.nature.com/articles/nrc.2017.32). Some photosensitizers seem to cause damage to the mitochondria trough reactive oxygen species (https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphar.2020.557429/full).